# Previous File History command in powershell

Tags: powershell

the business I work at told me to enable the function previous file history which is found in "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\File History" to all the computers, I don't want to do it manually so I'm trying to write a script for it.

```
$folderPath = "C:\Backup"
$shareName = "Backup"
$driveLetter = "X"
$newFolderName = "Backup"

$folderPath = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $folderPath -Name $newFolderName

New-SmbShare -Name $shareName -Path $folderPath -FullAccess "Everyone"

New-PSDrive -Name $driveLetter -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\$shareName" -Persist
```

The company I work at is a small IT company, and since most of our customers don't have a server and only one storage device connected to the pc, I'm bypassing that by creating a local network drive.

Now, issue is I don't know the command if there is a command to automatically enable previous file history.

This is a long shot, and I apologize for my bad script (I'm very new to PowerShell)

Thanks

Hey, just a small update, a large number of the computers are using windows 10 home, and I'm not sure if I want to download GPO through DISM or anything.

Again though I'm very new, so if anyone has any solutions please do advice.

Comment: This is what Group Policy is for...